# Executing Python script from Java - Issues with parameter passing

Tags: java, python, parameters, parameter-passing

I'm trying to execute a python script from Java. When I manually execute the python script, it works normally. When I execute it from Java, it has issues with the parameters: in fact, python responds with the "Usage" error, as if I didn't pass the parameters.

Java code:

```
            String pythonCommand="python /path/to/myscript.py --key='value list here' -otherparam=param";
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(pythonCommand);

            String line;
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader error = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
            p.waitFor();
            logger.debug("Exit value: "+p.exitValue());
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                logger.debug("Python command output: " +line);
            }
            while ((line = error.readLine()) != null) {
                logger.debug("Python command ERROR output: " +line);
            }
            input.close();
```

I repeat, the script works normally if I just copy-paste & execute literally what's in my "pythonCommand" String, but if I execute it from Java, it says:

```
2016-05-30 09:46:32 [threadName] DEBUG - Executing command: python /path/to/myscript.py --key='value list here' -otherparam=param
2016-05-30 09:46:32 [threadName] DEBUG - Exit value: 1
2016-05-30 09:46:32 [threadName] DEBUG - Python command ERROR output: Usage:
2016-05-30 09:46:32 [threadName] DEBUG - Python command ERROR output:   myscript.py [--key=<value list here>] --otherparam=<param>
2016-05-30 09:46:32 [threadName] DEBUG - Python command ERROR output:   myscript.py (-h | --help)
2016-05-30 09:46:32 [threadName] DEBUG - Python command ERROR output:   myscript.py --version
```

What's the problem here?

edit: Another important information! If I execute a Python script without parameters, such as "python /path/to/test.py" it works perfectly.

edit2: I have tried executing a Python script that does not contain multi-word parameters with ' or ", and it worked. So the multiword parameters are the issue, definitely. How should I pass them?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember you have to split your commandline into a String[] like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"python","/path/to/myscript.py", "--key", "value list here", "-otherparam", "param"});
```

Comment: Sorry, that did not work. I had to use pythonCommand.split(" ") because I'm not building the command , but it's passed to my function.

    String [] commands = pythonCommand.split(" ");
    logger.debug("Executing command: "+commands);

    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);

Comment: Also, from my furher tests, it looks like the multi-word parameters (containing spaces in them) are the issue.

Comment: If your value list contains whitespaces as shown in the example ('value list here') a simple split() will mess up your command. What is the output of your logger.debug("Executing command: "+commands);?

Comment: I had to use Arrays.toString(commands) otherwise it printed a useless toString representation of a Java array (something like String@somenumbers).

The output is something like:

Executing command: [python, /path/to/myscript.py, --key='some, value, here', --key2=test]

So you're completely right, the command is messed up. How can I solve this?